# djangoappengine email not arriving

Tags: django, google-app-engine, email

I am building a Django app for Google App engine with djangoappengine and I tried several configurations to send email but is not working, currently I have the following setting.py

```
enter code here

EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myemail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypassword'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

default email_backend and on views.py

```
enter code here
def contato(request):
    email = EmailMessage('Assunto teste', 'Aqui vai o corpo do email',from_email='myemail@gmail.com', to=['toemail@gmail.com'])
    email.send(fail_silently = True)
    return render(request, 'paginas/contato.html')
```

On the App Engine admin, the recipients emailed quota keep counting everytime I request "contato", from what I assume the email was sended, but I never receive the email.
Could someone point me in the right direction on how I should configure my app to send email on Google app Engine ? And What I am missing ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
fromHeader = "...."
email = EmailMessage(
    subject, message, 'myemail@gmail.com',
    ['toemail@gmail.com',],
    headers={'Reply-To': 'myemail@gmail.com', 'From': fromHeader})
email.send()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Catherine. Sorry the delay on the response, I got it to work on the same day and I forgot to comeback here. I appreciate your help, I have another question about the datastore access slow, any help is welcome. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21610655/django-nonrel-database-access-is-slow